# Problem making text as times new roman font with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, geom-text

Hi I am struggling to change the font of my ggplot to times new roman. I've tried multiple ideas from here but none seem to work. Any help would be much appreciated, and I will leave the code below:

```
Dallasdeck_infex <- ggplot(Alldata, aes(Date)) + geom_tile(aes(alpha = Recession, y = 1), 
        fill = "grey", height = Inf) + scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0, 1), breaks = c(0, 1), labels = c("0" = "Expansion", "1" = "Recession"))+ geom_line(aes(y = INFEX), col = "blue", size = .8)+ ylab('Infation Expectations (%)')+ labs(x = NULL, alpha = "Economic Cylcle", color = "Economic Variable",
   title = "Rising Inflation Expectations in 2021",
   caption = 'Cleveland Fed Model of 10-year Inflation Expectations',
   subtitle = '"Directionality Matters"')+ theme(plot.background = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major= element_blank(),
    text = element_text(color = "#CC0E44", family = "Times New Roman")) 
Dallasdeck_infex
```

Comment: If you're using RStudio, have you switched the Graphics Device in General - Graphics to "AGG"? It simplifies font rendering. Otherwise you may need to load extrafont or showtext or another package to set up your R session to handle more than the handful the traditional R graphics device could handle. More on AGG/RAGG here: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/modern-text-features/

Answer (score -1):

font-family

have you tried using font-family instead of just family?

Comment: I am not seeing a font-family function. Do you mean font_families()?

Comment: yes because in your code you just have family that could be the issue.

Comment: Ok what would be the syntax to add in times new roman font with font_families()?